# SQL Server--Setting column value during insert using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, triggers, xquery

I have a table with the following columns:

id, xml, receivedDate, processed, processedDateTime, orderNumber

id, receivedDate, and processed all have default values.

The XML being stored in the xml column looks like this:

```
<v1:OrderStatus xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.dell.com/Services/DMT/OrderStatus/V1">
  <v1:BusinessUnitId>11</v1:BusinessUnitId>
  <v1:OrderNumber>964806604</v1:OrderNumber>
  <v1:OrderStatusCode>RDD</v1:OrderStatusCode>
  <v1:StatusDateTime>2016-04-12T01:16:28</v1:StatusDateTime>
  <v1:RDD_Date>2016-04-19T00:00:00</v1:RDD_Date>
</v1:OrderStatus>
```

When the XML is inserted to the table, I need to grab the value for OrderNumber and set it in the orderNumber column.  I developed a trigger to try to accomplish this, but instead of setting the the value in only the newly inserted row, it sets the value for ALL the rows in the table.

My trigger looks like:

```
  declare @ordernumber varchar(50)  
  select @ordernumber=(select xml.value('(//*:OrderNumber)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as orderNumber from inserted)

    Update [dbo].[dell.des.OCIMessages] 
    set orderNumber=@ordernumber
      END
```

I have another trigger on a different table which joins on the orderNumber value between these two tables and I use this other trigger after an insert/update to find the row with the matching orderNumber and processed=0 and then set processed=1 and also set the processedDateTime field.

Unfortunately, since my first trigger is updating all the rows to use the same order number value, my second trigger inadvertently always updates all the rows because the ordernumber values are the same for every row in my table.

Can someone please shed some light on what is wrong with my trigger so that it only updates just the inserted row?

BTW, I'm only ever inserting a single row at a time, so I don't have to worry about my trigger have to deal with multiple records.

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly disagree that you can count on only ever having a single row insert. That may be true from the application but what data maintenance and that sort of thing? You should make your trigger set based. As for the actual problem at hand you have two issues. First your update statement has no where clause so it will update the entire table. Second is that if you are trying to "intercept" and change the inserted values you should use an instead of trigger and create the insert inside your trigger.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: ended up changing my trigger to this:                  declare @ordernumber varchar(50) select @ordernumber=(select xml.value('(//*:OrderNumber)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as orderNumber from inserted) Update [dbo].[dell.des.OCIMessages] set orderNumber=@ordernumber from [dell.des.OCIMessages] inner join inserted on [dell.des.OCIMessages].id=inserted.id END which seems to work. I like some of the other approaches presented. So I understand, what's wrong with my current implementation?

Comment: Well, if it works for you, there's nothing wrong. But: Whenever you try to insert more than one at once, this will break. Sooner or later this will happen... A computed column (may be defined as `persistent` to avoid repeated calculation) would even react if your XML changes. The `Instead Of Trigger` let's you gain full control on the process of insertion. Both approaches are much better and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a where condition on your update:

```
declare @ordernumber varchar(50), @id int 
select @ordernumber= xml.value('(//*:OrderNumber)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as orderNumber, @id = id from inserted

Update [dbo].[dell.des.OCIMessages] 
set orderNumber=@ordernumber 
where id = @id
  END
```

Or you could just use the set-based option:

```
Update oci Set oci.orderNumber = inserted.xml.value('(//*:OrderNumber)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from [dbo].[dell.des.OCIMessages] oci join inserted on oci.id = inserted.id
```

Comment: This will not work because the OP stated this is an insert trigger. As such the row does not yet exist in the base table.

Comment: It's after insert, so the row does exist.  It's not an interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

You need a unser defined function to retrieve your value

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetOrderNumber(@xml xml)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @xml.value('(//*:OrderNumber)[1]', 'varchar(max)');
END
```

#### Define your table with a computed column

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(id INT, xml XML, OrderNumber AS dbo.GetOrderNumber(xml));
```

And this is how it works

```
declare @xml1 xml=
'<v1:OrderStatus xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.dell.com/Services/DMT/OrderStatus/V1">
  <v1:OrderNumber>11111</v1:OrderNumber>
</v1:OrderStatus>';

declare @xml2 xml=
'<v1:OrderStatus xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.dell.com/Services/DMT/OrderStatus/V1">
  <v1:OrderNumber>22222</v1:OrderNumber>
</v1:OrderStatus>';

declare @xml3 xml=
'<v1:OrderStatus xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.dell.com/Services/DMT/OrderStatus/V1">
  <v1:OrderNumber>33333</v1:OrderNumber>
</v1:OrderStatus>';    

insert into dbo.Test VALUES(1,@xml1),(2,@xml2);

select * from dbo.Test;

insert into dbo.Test select 3,@xml3;

select * from dbo.Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

I place a second answer, because this is a completely differing approach:

Create a normal table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(id INT, xml XML, OrderNumber VARCHAR(100));
```

#### Create an "INSTEAD OF" Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InsertToTest ON  dbo.Test
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test(id,xml,OrderNumber)
    SELECT id,xml,xml.value('(//*:OrderNumber)[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
    FROM inserted
END
GO
```

And this is how it works

```
declare @xml1 xml=
'<v1:OrderStatus xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.dell.com/Services/DMT/OrderStatus/V1">
  <v1:OrderNumber>11111</v1:OrderNumber>
</v1:OrderStatus>';

declare @xml2 xml=
'<v1:OrderStatus xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.dell.com/Services/DMT/OrderStatus/V1">
  <v1:OrderNumber>22222</v1:OrderNumber>
</v1:OrderStatus>';

declare @xml3 xml=
'<v1:OrderStatus xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.dell.com/Services/DMT/OrderStatus/V1">
  <v1:OrderNumber>33333</v1:OrderNumber>
</v1:OrderStatus>';    

insert into dbo.Test VALUES(1,@xml1,'SomeValue'),(2,@xml2,'AnotherValue');

select * from dbo.Test;

insert into dbo.Test select 3,@xml3,null;

select * from dbo.Test;
```